# updating existing value every one hour if the condition is valid

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to update existing value every one hour if the condition is valid

is it possible to write if statement inside event ?

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'add one every hour if its lees than 10 '
DO
if score > 10
    UPDATE my_table SET score=score+1 WHERE ID=1
```

Comment: OK, fine with us. Any questions you have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ask specific programming questions, don't just write some code with a comment on what it should do. The community is here to help, but you should do your part by asking clear, understandable questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry about that the question is is it possible to write if statement inside event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Just three problems with your code:

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR /*Problem 1: This is every 1 hour starting from the time you created the event. Probably not what you want.*/
COMMENT 'add one every hour if its lees than 10 '
DO /*Problem 2: You'll have multiple statements here. Tell this MySQL or it will think that your event declaration will be finished after the first statement.*/
if score > 10 /*Problem 3: The computer will ask "which score?"*/
    UPDATE my_table SET score=score+1 WHERE ID=1
```

Write your code like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR
  STARTS '2014-03-12 09:00:00'
COMMENT 'add one every hour if its lees than 10 '
DO
BEGIN
SET @my_score = (SELECT score FROM my_table WHERE ID = 1);
IF (@my_score > 10) THEN
    UPDATE my_table SET score=score+1 WHERE ID=1;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @8amer Please note, that you will run into more issues with Ravinder's answer. Consider mine :)

Comment: problem *3 i did it on purpose but thanks.problem 1 yes i want the event to be every Hour ,why i can't do that ?

Comment: and problem 3 is no issue?

Comment: sorry i meant problem 3

Comment: Problem 1 It will run every hour, but with your code not necessarily on every full hour. You did problem 3 on purpose? But your code won't run like that?

Comment: i want my code to run once every hour not the whole hour  !

Comment: Yes, once an hour. But your code will run at 10:34 and 11:34 and 12:34 if you created it 9:34. Not at a specified time like 10:00 then 11:00 and so on.

Comment: ahaaa now i get it,,,Thanks

Comment: The usual way to say thanks here is to accept the answer that helped you the most. :)

Comment: @fancyPants: You stealer .... :) Just kidding. Cool ... I just gave a solution for *`whether we can use if condition ..`*. For rest of the part, I thought, OP is aware on what he is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have `IF` or any other conditions and multi statement code blocks in an `event` definition.

When you have multiple statements to be processed, you need to enclose them between `begin` - `end`.

**Example**:

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'add one every hour if its lees than 10 '
DO
  BEGIN
    if ( score > 10 ) THEN
      UPDATE my_table SET score=score+1 WHERE ID=1;
    elseif  ( score < 10 ) THEN
      -- add your statement here
    else
      -- add your statement here
    end if;
  END;
```

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL: Create Event Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Comment: thanks,that what i was missing i thought that i can't but an if statement inside event

Comment: Make sure that, in your above code, you declare a variable `score` and assign a value for it. Without which, it throws an error.